# Framework design with user extensible classes?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Consider the following class diagram:

[image: Framework design - class diagram]

`ModelA` and `ModelB` are framework classes, `MyModelA` and `MyModelB` are classes the user of the framework defines.

The `proceed()` method is used by the framework and is to be implemented by the user. Obviously, the implementation can use the methods of `ModelA`.

It should be possible for the user to refine the `ModelA` class (e.g. add additional data records) and pass objects of the extended class (`MyModelA`) to the framework to work with.

The problem is now to design the framework in a way such that the implementation of `proceed()` can also use the methods of `MyModelA`, in this example `getMyValue()`.

Is there a standard design pattern which addresses this problem?

The following possible solutions may also clarify the problem:

#### 1. Casting

If the user of the framework knows which `ModelA` classes he is using, he could cast the `ModelA` parameter to the correct type in the `proceed()` implementation.
Surely this is a little cumbersome and not clean.

#### 2. Using template parameters

To keep type safety, the framework could be parameterized with a type parameter which is used to parameterize `ModelB`. In Java:

```java
public class ModelB<T extends ModelA> {
  public abstract void proceed(T data);
}
```

In this way, the following is possible, as desired:

```java
public class MyModelB extends ModelB<MyModelA> {
  public abstract void proceed(MyModelA data) {
    data.getMyValue();
  }
}
```

But this can get quite inconvenient, especially if the same problem occurs with more classes and you would have to introduce multiple type parameters.
In addition, it does not seem very flexible.

#### 3. Provide basic data model in `ModelA` [limited]

When it is only desired that the user should be able to add custom data to `ModelA`, would it be a considerable solution to provide a more or less flexible data storage system?

Example: A "tree dictionary", i.e. one can store key-value pairs of standard data types and index them with a multi-level key: `data.getString(["fruits", "apple", "small"])`.

### Update 1

To clarify what the requirements are:
Think of `ModelA` to represent players of a game and `ModelB` to represent some actions the players can perform. The framework defines a general player class and an abstract `proceed()` method. The application that uses the framework adds player functionality in `MyModelA` that can be used in the actions in `MyModelB`. The actions are not directly called by the application, but by the framework (e.g. the application schedules the calls).

Comment: Is it necessary to pass the `ModelA` object as a parameter or can it exist as an association of the `ModelB` class? Then you don't have to care about all of this.

Comment: The framework keeps multiple `ModelA` objects (which actually are `MyModelA`). The user of the framework writes different `ModelB` implementations, whose `proceed()` methods are invoked by the framework, with varying `ModelA` objects.
So the parameter seems necessary to me, or can you explain further what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

What is real need to define

```cs
public abstract class ModelB
{
   public abstract void Proceed(ModelA a);
}
```

not

```cs
public abstract class ModelB
{
    public abstract void Proceed();
}
```

if you actually don't use ModelA a in base class ModelB?

That's it may look like:

**Command-like solution**

```cs
public abstract class ModelB
{
    public abstract void Proceed();
}

public class MyModelB : ModelB
{
    //inject via constructor
    private readonly MyModelA _a;
    public void Proceed() 
    {
       //do somthing with a
    }
}
```

or

```cs
public abstract class ModelB
{
    public abstract void Proceed(ModelA a);
    protected abstract ModelA ModelA { get; }
}

public class MyModelB : ModelB
{
    //inject via constructor
    private readonly MyModelA _a;
    public void Proceed() 
    {
       //do somthing with a
    }

    protected override ModelA ModelA
    {
        get { return _a; }
    }
}
```

Thinking in this way take a look at the Command pattern:

```cs
public abstract class Command
{
    public abstract void Run();

    public abstract ModelA Argument { get; }
}

public abstract class ModelB
{
    //not abstract
    public void Proceed(Command command)
    {
        command.Run();
    }        
}
```

Ok, if you actually have to do this, I think safe cast to be best solution:

**Safe cast**

```cs
public class MyModelB : ModelB
{
    public override void Proceed(ModelA a)
    {
        if (a is MyModelA)
        {
            var myA = (MyModelA) a;
            //do something with a
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I added information to the question. I am not sure if I understood what you mean. Do you think this still applies regarding my update?